# Python Requests - Forbidden Error (Directory issue i.e. ../ reduction )

Tags: python, python-requests

**Code**

```
hostDir = 'https://www.example.com/a/b/'
path = '../../script.js'
x = hostDir + path
import requests
print(requests.get(x).content.decode('utf-8'))
```

When I run above code, it gives following error:

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Access Denied</H1>

You don't have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;www&#46;xyz&#46;com&#47;a&#47;b&#47;&#46;&#46;&#47;&#46;&#46;&#47;script&#46;js" on this server.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;18&#46;3da21ab8&#46;1546852663&#46;7da6a685
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I can see that this issue is due to path '../../' and '/a/b/' but requests module is not able to convert it to 'https://www.example.com/scripts.js'

Considering '../../' and '/a/b/' both can be any number of times.

Please help me out to deal with this problem so that it can be converted into 'https://www.example.com/scripts.js'

Comment: Thanks I got it :)

Comment: Are you trying to implement something recursive to get data? `x = hostDir + path` will give you `'https://www.example.com/a/b/../../script.js'`. Is this not what you want?

Comment: I want 'https://www.example.com/scripts.js'

Comment: Thanks, I see what your duplicate answer meant.